# DNS Server for my home netwoek

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, dhcp

I have a number of virtual machines all running on my ESXi host. These all connect to my home router, and are assigned an IP address through DHCP.

When I go to connect to these VMs, they frequently have different IP addresses than last time, so I need to check the DHCP lease list before I can connect to one of these machines. (SSH, HTTP, FTP, etc.)

What I would like to do: I would like to set up a DNS server, allowing me to create URLs for these machines.

I envision something like `nas.local.net` would redirect to `192.168.1.138` and `esx.local.net` would map to `192.168.1.101`

Furthermore, I would prefer to not need to make static IPs at my router for all of these addresses. Optimally, this service would associate MAC address with URL, and make the IP mapping with that information.

Is there any way to create this kind of mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Your router probably acts as DHCP server. You could try to **increase the DHCP lease time**. This would make IP address changes less frequent. Many routers allow a direct 1:1 assignment of MAC addresses and IP addresses. Typically, this is done in the DHCP configuration menu. However, this would block IP addresses for VMs which might not be used.

Another approach would be to reserve a certain address range in your local network for virtual machines and set them up with **static IP addresses**.

You most likely already have a **local DNS server in your router**. It "knows" the local addresses administered by its DHCP server and forwards other addresses to some external DNS server. Look at the router documentation.